# Creating a test branch in CI with git

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration

In our CI system, we need to create a test branch from master HEAD and pull in changes from a couple of branches. And then send the branch for testing. We use git and our repo is massive. The test branch will be disposed after the test. We are just interest in the test result because we use github to merge branches individually. I face a couple of issues.

1. It takes almost 15min to checkout.
2. Some branches are almost 200+ commits behind the master.

I'm looking for a fast and reliable method to create this test branch.

I tried to use `--depth 1` when cloning the repo. It seems to reduce the clone time from 15min to 5min. but I'm not sure this will cause any issues in getting feature branch changes.

This is what I do.

```
git clone https://github.com/myorg/myrepo
git checkout -b testBranch
```

for each feature branch

```
START_COMMIT_ID="$(git merge-base remotes/origin/feature_xxx master)"
LATEST_COMMIT_ID="$(git rev-parse feature_xxx)" 
git fetch origin feature_xxx
git diff "${START_COMMIT_ID)".."${LATEST_COMMIT_ID}" | git apply -
git add .
git commit -m "test branch"
```

and finally

```
git push origin
```

Am I doing the right thing? Is there any improvement in speed and reliability?

Comment: Can you just merge each branch in instead of creating patches?

Comment: I tried using `git merge --no-ff --no-edit`. but it took too long and printing message like `Performing inexact rename detection`